# How to extend Material UI 3 theme Typescript definition with the Material UI pickers theme

Tags: typescript, material-ui, themes

I try to extend the *Material-UI* theme to incorporate the *Typescript* typings of the *Material-UI-Pickers*, for the following (latest) versions:

```
"@material-ui/core": "^3.9.2",
"material-ui-pickers": "^2.2.1",
```

There's a mention at the bottom of the [Material UI picker](https://material-ui-pickers.firebaseapp.com/guides/css-overrides) page, explaining that the theme can be augmented thanks to [Typescript Theme augmentation](https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#customization-of-theme).

It recommends to do this:

```
declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/overrides' {
    import { MuiPickersOverrides } from 'material-ui-pickers/typings/overrides'
    export interface Overrides extends MuiPickersOverrides { }
}
```

But in the *Material UI* `override.d.ts` file, `Overrides` is not an *interface* but a *type* (so it won't be extensible this way), which makes me think the *Material-UI* typings have changed drastically, and that *Material-UI-Pickers* guide (and typings) are outdated.

Any clue about how to extend correctly the theme typings?

Comment: Have you tried this approach? If so what errors did you see?

Comment: @epsilon Of course I tried. It complains that `Overrides` already exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution.
Indeed, *MuiPickers* use a *property name -> style rules* mapping, whereas the latest versions of *Material UI* use a *property name -> classes names* mapping.

Creating a `overrides-mui.d.ts` file that contains the following solves the problem.

```
import { Overrides } from "@material-ui/core/styles/overrides";
import { MuiPickersOverrides } from 'material-ui-pickers/typings/overrides'

type overridesNameToClassKey = { [P in keyof MuiPickersOverrides]: keyof 
MuiPickersOverrides[P] }

declare module "@material-ui/core/styles/overrides" {
    export interface ComponentNameToClassKey extends overridesNameToClassKey { }
}
```

Only issues are with style selectors such as `&$selected`.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me and TS complains `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'MuiPickersBasePicker' does not exist in type 'Overrides'`. I declared the module inside the `theme.ts` file which exports `createTheme()`. "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3", "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10". Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: Indeed, this answer was related to Material-UI 3.x and the pickers 2.x. It still works with MUI 4, but with the pickers 2.x. I'll try to upgrade them and see how it goes.